# Reload UITableView not functioning in IOS5

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reload

The UITableview reloadData function is not calling the cellforRowAtIndexPath method. Following things I had tried:

1. Call `[self.myTableView reloadData];`
2. call `reloadData` method on `ViewWillAppear` too.
3. written `self.myTableView.delegate=self;` and `self.myTableView.datasource=self` too.
4. Also I have test using NSLog that number of rows are updating properly.
5. Data source and delegate are connected in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Does your view conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDatasource`?

And does it at least implement all of the required methods in those protocols? also, there's no need to say `self.myTableView`, you could just say `myTableView` if you're working inside of the class.

And it sounds silly, but did you forget to save your storyboard? I've done that on more than one occasion.

Comment: when you build or run the program, XCode saves the unsaved changes and then compile the code.

Comment: It doesn't save in the older versions... but he did say he was using storyboard, so I guess he's using the newer version.

Comment: It is Autosaving.All the datasource and delegate methods are implemented.

Comment: Also one important thing, I am using custom cell using storyboard,with Correct Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't declared delegate in your .h file.

Example.

```
@interface ClassName:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: I have declare it, as well as UITableViewDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the method?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; //Return the number of sections you want
}
```

It's easy to forget, since by default it returns 0.

If you don't do it the tableview thinks it has no sections and does not ask for any row.

Comment: Yes, I did this. Also one important thing, I am using custom cell using storyboard,with Correct Identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the table view's delegate:

```
tableView.delegate = _an_object_that_conforms_to_UITableViewDelegate_;
```

This is normally the view controller in which you've declared the table view so you would have:

```
tableView.delegate = self;
```

Just make sure the view controller that contains the table view and acts as it's delegate declares itself as an UITableViewDelegate:

```
@class MyViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

  UITableView *tableView;
  ...
```

Comment: Yes, I did this. Also one important thing, I am using custom cell using storyboard,with Correct Identifier.